# XML parsing in android.not working

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a few Java files that I have to try and get info from an XML on the internet. I made the files with the help of some tutorials online but I can't find the problem with what I have.

Below are the three classes I used.

MainXMLClass.java

```
public class News extends ActionBarActivity {

static final String baseURL = "http://coderdojo.com/rss.xml";

ListView News;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    xmlRefs();
    GetURLData();

    ArrayList<String> XMLData = new ArrayList<>();
    XMLData.add(XMLDataCollected.GetXMLData());

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.id.lvNews, XMLData);

    News.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void xmlRefs() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    News = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNews);
}

private void GetURLData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        URL webPage = new URL(baseURL);
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();

        XMLDataHandler Data = new XMLDataHandler();
        reader.setContentHandler(Data);
        reader.parse(new InputSource(webPage.openStream()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

My XMLHandler.java Class:

```
public class XMLDataHandler extends DefaultHandler {

XMLDataCollected Info = new XMLDataCollected();

public String getInformation() {
    return XMLDataCollected.GetXMLData();
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (localName.equals("title")) {
        String title = localName.getBytes().toString();
        Info.setTitle(title);
    } else if (localName.equals("link")) {
        String link = localName.getBytes().toString();
        Info.setLink(link);
    } else if (localName.equals("description")) {
        String description = localName.getBytes().toString();
        Info.setDescription(description);
    }
}
}
```

And finally my XMLDataCollected.java class:

```
public class XMLDataCollected {

static String title;
static String description;
static String link;

public void setTitle(String t) {
    title = t;
}

public void setDescription(String d) {
    description = d;
}

public void setLink(String l) {
    link = l;
}

public static String GetXMLData() {
    return title + description + link;
}
}
```

I've been trying for about three days to get this sorted but so far I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere.

This is my first time trying to use XML parsing so I'm aware there is bound to be a few things wrong with the files but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but are you SURE about that URL, as I understand, this is the final URL : http://coderdojo.com/news?page=0 or some other number. But when I typed into the browser, the result is not XML format.

Comment: I just realised I was taking the wrong link. Thanks.